# Do Arbitrary initial velocity field satisfies Hamilton-Jacobi equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

Would The trajectory of particles  arrive at the same position with different velocity?Or two particles shocks if define initial velocity field arbitrarily but continuous? 
I can understand  in  grativity field  two particles start at the same height ,one particle with horizontal velocity toward another particle,they would shock. However two separate particle can not generate continuous initial velocity field.
Thanks